# What type would you map BigDecimal in Java/Hibernate in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, numbers, bigdecimal

After going through the previous develop's trainwreck of code I realized I need to move all of the money based columns to not use floating point math.  On the Java side this means using BigDecimal but when using Hibernate/JPA and MySQL 5 what would be the appropriate MySQL data type to make that column?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

DECIMAL and NUMERIC.

> The recommended Java mapping for the DECIMAL and NUMERIC  types is
> java.math.BigDecimal. The `java.math.BigDecimal`  type provides math
> operations to allow BigDecimal types  to be added, subtracted,
> multiplied, and divided with other  BigDecimal types, with integer
> types, and with floating point types.
>
> The method recommended for retrieving DECIMAL and NUMERIC  values is
> ResultSet.getBigDecimal. JDBC also allows access to these SQL types
> as simple Strings or arrays of char.  Thus, Java programmers can use
> getString to receive a  DECIMAL or NUMERIC result. However, this makes
> the common case where DECIMAL or NUMERIC are used for currency values rather awkward since it means that application writers have to
> perform math on strings. It is also possible to retrieve these SQL
> types as any of the Java numeric types.

Have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html) for further details.

Comment: Updated link : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html